# How to download many email attachments from gmail

Tags: download, email-attachments, gmail-api

I have a device that sends daily statistics as an attachment to an email address at gmail. A filter identifies the sender and sequesters the mails into a folder in the mailbox. Currently ~2000 emails have accumulated. I need to download these attachments so the data can be aggregated and analyzed. I supposed I could write a macro to move the mouse, click the right places on the screen, etc. but was wondering if there is a programmatic way to simply download all the attachments from all the emails in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gmail API to retrieve attachments: 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get#examples